# Formulation of questions by using conditional sentences

Tags: questions

Consider the following setences:

1st - Interestingly, If the Titanic HAD HIT the iceberg head on, she would not have sunk. (third condiotnal)

2nd -  If you had a million dollars, you would travel the world. (second conditional)

In order to form questions, would it be true if I said that we can only form them by using the result? For example:

If the Titanic HAD HIT the iceberg head on, (condition)
 she would not have sunk (result)

- If the Titanic HAD HIT the iceberg head on, wouldn't she have sunk? (question)

  - If you had a million dollars, WOULD you travel the world?

Would it be possible to say: HAD you a million dollars, you would travel the world?

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean "only form them by using the result"?

Answer (score -1):

If you had a million dollars, you would travel the world.

This sentence is conditional type 2.  I think it should be in the inverted form as follows:

Were you to have a million dollars, you would travel the world.

These sentences should be in the interrogative as follows:

If you had a million dollars, would you travel the world?

Were you to have a million dollars, would you travel the world?

Look at the following sentences that are conditional type 3:

If you had had a million dollars, you would have travelled the world.

Had you had a million dollars, you would have travelled the world.

These sentences should be in the interrogative as follows:

If you had had a million dollars, would you have travelled the world?

Had you had a million dollars, would you have travelled the world?

Comment: Thank you very much. In summary, it's possible to invert both the auxiliary verb in the condition and the result to form question, but only in formal English:

HAD you a million dollars, WOULD you travel the word? (formal)

In everyday speech, native speakers form questions by inverting the result (the second auxiliary verb):

If you had a million dollars, WOULD you travel the world?

Am I right?

Comment: Peter Ferrer, the sentence "Had you a million dollars, ......."  doesn't seem correct. It should be "Were you to have......."   Look at my revised answer.

Comment: **were you to** is not the inverted form of **if you had**. It's the inverted form of *if you were to have*. The inverted form of the had version is **had you...** And yes you can say *Had you a million dollars,...* and follow it with either the declarative  *you would* or they interrogative *would you?* but both are  uncommon in everyday English.